# Nested OR, AND in CriteriaBuilder, Predicate

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria

writing following criteria

```
    Date vardate = 'Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2100';    
    public Predicate toPredicate(
                        Root<T> root,
                        CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {               
                        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();  
                            predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get(LINE_OF_BUSINESS_ID), lobId));
//Predicate a = cb.and(cb.isNotNull(stateSuretyRates.<Date>get(EXP_DATE)),
                            cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(stateSuretyRates.<Date>get(EXP_DATE),effDate));
        return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
        }
```

and query is

```
select ... from table t Where t.business = 1 and
(
(t.StartA <= 'some EndB') and (t.EndA >= 'some StartB') and (t.EndA is not null) and ('some EndB' is not null)
OR
(t.StartA <= 'some EndB') and (vardate >= 'some StartB') and (t.EndA is null) and ('some EndB' is not null)
OR
(t.StartA <= vardate) and (t.EndA >= 'some StartB') and (t.EndA is not null) and ('some EndB' is null)
OR
(t.StartA <= vardate) and (vardate >= 'some StartB') and (t.EndA is null) and ('some EndB' is null)
)
```

Please suggest, how to write predicate and predicates

Comment: Did you manage to get a solution?